Crash after editing TextView text from MainActivity.kt
I'm new to Kotlin. I'm trying to take Email from firebase authentication to show it on menu to show from which email user signed in. I got email in variable.
After trying to change text of TextView from MainActivity.kt by method textview.text or textview.setText or another my app doesn't even run.
MainActivity.kt:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: MainactivityBinding = MainactivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        var email_textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_email)
        val drawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout)
        val buttonDrawerToggle = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.buttonDrawerToggle)
        val navigationView = findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigationView)

        buttonDrawerToggle.setOnClickListener() {
            drawerLayout.open()
        }

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val userEmail: String = user!!.email.toString()
        email_textview.text = userEmail
    }
}

And this is drawer_header:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#F8D5A1"
    android:padding="20dp"
    >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFC107">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:contentDescription="NULL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/person"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

Hope someone will help me

Please also provide the stack trace from the crash.

There is too much symbols in Stack Trace. Can`t add by comment

It doesn't belong in the comments, it should be part of the question. Please [edit] it and paste the stracktrace there.

Can`t edit, because Stack Trace is too massive(entered 31590, limit 30000 ). I'ma just delete the answer or wait someone help with Stack Trace

We only need the stracktrace, not the entire log file. That will be arond 50 lines or so.

instead of this line
var email_textview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_email)
        

Directly access TextView from Binding try this
binding.textEmail


In MainActivity I made variable binding for DrawerHeaderBinding, and did what you wrote but anyway TextView doesn't change, atleast app now runs
